# Application layout fixed header of angular components with angularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-components, dart-html, dart-webui

I am trying to fixed the header and drawer in the app layout with the following code, but the header navigation is not responsive, the navigation items shifts to its right out of the screen. As the results are in the second image after running the additional code.

```
/* Drawer */
material-drawer .adf-drawer {
  position: fixed;
}


/* Header */
material-content header {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Header error image
[image]

[image]

Drawer error image[image]
app_layout.html

```
<material-drawer persistent #drawer="drawer" [attr.end]="end ? '' : null">
    <material-list *deferredContent class="adf-drawer">
        <div group class="mat-drawer-spacer"></div>
        <div group>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="inbox"></material-icon>Inbox
            </material-list-item>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="star"></material-icon>Star
            </material-list-item>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="send"></material-icon>Sent Mail
            </material-list-item>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="drafts"></material-icon>Drafts
            </material-list-item>
        </div>
        <div group>
            <div label>Tags</div>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="star"></material-icon>Favorites
            </material-list-item>
        </div>
    </material-list>
</material-drawer>
<material-content>
    <header class="material-header shadow">
        <div class="material-header-row">
            <material-button icon
                             class="material-drawer-button" (trigger)="drawer.toggle()">
                <material-icon icon="menu"></material-icon>
            </material-button>
            <span class="material-header-title visible-desktop">AngularDart + Firebase</span>
            <span class="material-header-title visible-mobile">AD + FB</span>
            <div class="material-spacer"></div>
            <nav class="material-navigation">
                <a href="#AppLayout">Link 2</a>
            </nav>
            <nav class="material-navigation">
                <material-button icon>
                    <material-icon icon="more_vert"></material-icon>
                </material-button>
            </nav>
            <login-logout></login-logout>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
        et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
        veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
        legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.

    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <h3>Options</h3>
        <material-toggle [(checked)]="end" label="end">
        </material-toggle>
    </div>
</material-content>
```

app_layout.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/app_layout/material_persistent_drawer.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/content/deferred_content.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_button/material_button.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_icon/material_icon.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_list/material_list.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_list/material_list_item.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_toggle/material_toggle.dart';
import 'package:yns_app/src/component/login-logout/login_logout_component.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'app-layout',
    directives: const [
      materialDirectives,
      DeferredContentDirective,
      MaterialButtonComponent,
      MaterialIconComponent,
      MaterialListComponent,
      MaterialListItemComponent,
      MaterialPersistentDrawerDirective,
      MaterialToggleComponent,
      LoginLogoutComponent,
    ],
    templateUrl: 'app_layout.html',
    styleUrls: const [
      'app_layout.css',
      'package:angular_components/app_layout/layout.scss.css',
    ])
class AppLayoutComponent {
  bool end = false;
}
```

app_layout.scss

```
@import 'package:angular_components/css/material/material';

:host {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.controls {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:active, a:hover {
  color: $mat-white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Drawer */
material-drawer .adf-drawer {
  position: fixed;
}


/* Header */
material-content header {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app_component.html

```
<material-content>
<material-drawer persistent #drawer="drawer" [attr.end]="end ? '' : null">
    <material-list *deferredContent class="adf-drawer">
        <div group class="mat-drawer-spacer"></div>
        <div group>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="inbox"></material-icon>Inbox
            </material-list-item>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="star"></material-icon>Star
            </material-list-item>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="send"></material-icon>Sent Mail
            </material-list-item>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="drafts"></material-icon>Drafts
            </material-list-item>
        </div>
        <div group>
            <div label>Tags</div>
            <material-list-item>
                <material-icon icon="star"></material-icon>Favorites
            </material-list-item>
        </div>
    </material-list>
</material-drawer>
    <header class="material-header shadow">
        <div class="material-header-row">
            <material-button icon
                             class="material-drawer-button" (trigger)="drawer.toggle()">
                <material-icon icon="menu"></material-icon>
            </material-button>
            <span class="material-header-title visible-desktop">AngularDart + Firebase</span>
            <span class="material-header-title visible-mobile">AD + FB</span>
            <div class="material-spacer"></div>
            <nav class="material-navigation">
                <a href="#AppLayout">Link 2</a>
            </nav>
            <nav class="material-navigation">
                <material-button icon>
                    <material-icon icon="more_vert"></material-icon>
                </material-button>
            </nav>
            <login-logout></login-logout>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
        et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
        veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
        legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.

    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <h3>Options</h3>
        <material-toggle [(checked)]="end" label="end">
        </material-toggle>
    </div>
</material-content>
```

app_component.css

```
material-content material-drawer {
    position: fixed;
}

material-content header {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Did you use addition Css definitions? For me, toolbar is fixed, but all the components are under toolbar.

Comment: No I didn't use any additional css.